# Global object and creation order

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

I'm still learning C++. I have one problem. Lets say that your project has global object which always exists e.g `ApiManager` and all other modules have access to it (by `#include`). For now I'm doing it by:

Header:

```
class ApiManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ApiManager(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
public slots:
};

extern ApiManager apiMng;
```

Source:

```
ApiManager apiMng;
```

The problem is that other objects need to have access when initialized too and I noticed that C++ global objects are created alphabetically. I'm wondering how do you deal with it? Exists some trick for this? For example in Free Pascal world each class module has `initialization` and `finalization` sections:

```
Type
  TApiManager = class
end;

var ApiMng: TApiManager;

initialization
  ApiMng := TApiManager.Create;
finalization
  ApiMng.Free;
```

... and `initialization` order of project modules can be sorted in project source in `uses` clause (like `#include` in C++). I know that there is a lot of ways to do this (for example initialize everything in `main.cpp` with custom order) but want to know what is a "good habit" in C++ world

**Edit:** Solved by Q_GLOBAL_STATIC (introduced in Qt 5.1 but work for Qt 4.8 too) but still have two issues:

1. Still don't know how to manage constructor orders (and where to initialize it). Because global objects created by Q_GLOBAL_STATIC are not created at application startup. They are created on first usage. So I need to "touch" these object somewhere (in main.cpp?) with my custom order.
2. Documentation is saying that Q_GLOBAL_STATIC must be called in body .cpp file, not in header. But then other classes do not see this object. So I created static function which expose reference to this object:

.cpp:

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(ApiManager, apiMng)
ApiManager *ApiManager::instance()
{
    return apiMng();
}
```

But from this topic: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/13977 Q_GLOBAL_STATIC should expose instance automatically, but it doesn't

Comment: Ad 1). Well, maybe I didn't catch this in fight between C++ and Qt. Real example: Using Q_GLOBAL_STATIC is not enough, I need to do in main.cpp:

    // Initialize global objects
    ApiManager::instance();
    AmarokPlugin::instance();

Ad 2). Sorry. From this conversation I thought that Q_GLOBAL_STATIC is magically exposing instance() method, but I need define it by my self

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not initialized in alphabetical order, and the initialization order among the translation units are undefined as nothing is guaranteed by the standard about it.

> Why global variables are evil
>
> Global variables should be avoided for several reasons, but the primary reason is because they increase your program’s complexity immensely. For example, say you were examining a program and you wanted to know what a variable named g_nValue was used for. Because g_nValue is a global, and globals can be used anywhere in the entire program, you’d have to examine every single line of every single file! In a computer program with hundreds of files and millions of lines of code, you can imagine how long this would take!
>
> Second, global variables are dangerous because their values can be changed by any function that is called, and there is no easy way for the programmer to know that this will happen.
>
> Why Global Variables Should Be Avoided When Unnecessary
>
> Non-locality -- Source code is easiest to understand when the scope of its individual elements are limited. Global variables can be read or modified by any part of the program, making it difficult to remember or reason about every possible use.
>
> No Access Control or Constraint Checking -- A global variable can be get or set by any part of the program, and any rules regarding its use can be easily broken or forgotten. (In other words, get/set accessors are generally preferable over direct data access, and this is even more so for global data.) By extension, the lack of access control greatly hinders achieving security in situations where you may wish to run untrusted code (such as working with 3rd party plugins).
>   Implicit coupling -- A program with many global variables often has tight couplings between some of those variables, and couplings between variables and functions. Grouping coupled items into cohesive units usually leads to better programs.
>
> Concurrency issues -- if globals can be accessed by multiple threads of execution, synchronization is necessary (and too-often neglected). When dynamically linking modules with globals, the composed system might not be thread-safe even if the two independent modules tested in dozens of different contexts were safe.
>
> Namespace pollution -- Global names are available everywhere. You may unknowingly end up using a global when you think you are using a local (by misspelling or forgetting to declare the local) or vice versa. Also, if you ever have to link together modules that have the same global variable names, if you are lucky, you will get linking errors. If you are unlucky, the linker will simply treat all uses of the same name as the same object.
>   Memory allocation issues -- Some environments have memory allocation schemes that make allocation of globals tricky. This is especially true in languages where "constructors" have side-effects other than allocation (because, in that case, you can express unsafe situations where two globals mutually depend on one another). Also, when dynamically linking modules, it can be unclear whether different libraries have their own instances of globals or whether the globals are shared.
>
> Testing and Confinement - source that utilizes globals is somewhat more difficult to test because one cannot readily set up a 'clean' environment between runs. More generally, source that utilizes global services of any sort (e.g. reading and writing files or databases) that aren't explicitly provided to that source is difficult to test for the same reason. For communicating systems, the ability to test system invariants may require running more than one 'copy' of a system simultaneously, which is greatly hindered by any use of shared services - including global memory - that are not provided for sharing as part of the test.

In general, please avoid global variables as a rule of thumb. If you do need to have them, please use [Q_GLOBAL_STATIC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qglobalstatic.html#Q_GLOBAL_STATIC).

> Creates a global and static object of type QGlobalStatic, of name VariableName and that behaves as a pointer to Type. The object created by Q_GLOBAL_STATIC initializes itself on the first use, which means that it will not increase the application or the library's load time. Additionally, the object is initialized in a thread-safe manner on all platforms.

You can also use [Q_GLOBAL_STATIC_WITH_ARGS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qglobalstatic.html#Q_GLOBAL_STATIC_WITH_ARGS). Here you can find some inline highlight from the documentation:

> Creates a global and static object of type QGlobalStatic, of name VariableName, initialized by the arguments Arguments and that behaves as a pointer to Type. The object created by Q_GLOBAL_STATIC_WITH_ARGS initializes itself on the first use, which means that it will not increase the application or the library's load time. Additionally, the object is initialized in a thread-safe manner on all platforms.

Some people also tend to create a function for wrapping them, but they do not reduce the complexity significantly, and they eventually either forget to make those functions thread-safe, or they put more complexity in. Forget about doing that as well when you can.

Comment: Looks like ideal solution but Q_GLOBAL_STATIC was introduced in Qt 5.1 and I need for Qt 4.8 :/

Comment: Well, seems to work but see my first post, I edited it

Comment: Well, I don't understand stackoverflow idea, I wanted to explain everything in this comment to keep history, but comments have chars limit and I decided to just edit main post

Answer (score 6):

The initialization order of global objects is only defined within a translation unit (there it is top to bottom). There is no guarantee between translation units. The typical work-around is to wrap the object into a function and return a reference to a local object:

```
ApiManager& apiMng() {
    static ApiManager rc;
    return rc;
}
```

The local object is initialized the first time the function is called (and, when using C++11 also in a thread-safe fashion). This way, the order of construction of globally accessed objects can be ordered in a useful way.

That said, don't use global objects. They are causing more harm than good.

Comment: That is wrong IMHO. It is better to use Q_GLOBAL_STATIC than your hand crafted custom code.

Comment: Moreover, Q_GLOBAL_STATIC is thread safe unlike your hand crafted version.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: You may be rather fond of Qt but 1. it isn't part of the C++ standad, and 2. the C++ standard guarantees the thread safety of my approach (see 6.7 [stmt.dcl] paragraph 4 to convince yourself; the relevant statement is towards the end of this paragraph).

Comment: No, the C++ standard does not guarantee that, not at least with C++ 98/03. Moreover, it is a Qt program, so objecting to QtCore base features, and reinventing the wheel in a poor and buggy way is unreasonable.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I'm aware that the C++98 and C++03 don't talk about threads and don't make any guarantees about thread-safety. However, C++03 was replaced at the end of 2011 by C++11 which is the corrently relevant standard. Since you make statements about my code being "buggy", can you please point out _exactly_ where my code is incorrect and in which way?

Comment: I already did. Please read more carefully what I write. Your code is wrong. It will have undefined behavior for multi-threaded applications which have to work where Qt work. It is not suggesting a Qt solution which works with any kind of compiler that Qt support. It is buggy, it is mistakenly placed in this thread (as it is a Qt thread) in my opinion. I understand you did not know about what I wrote, but this is a Qt question after all. Qt is touch more versatile than just C++11 for which not even every feature is supposed everywhere.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I'm clearly seeing a C++ tag on this question and the initialization is definitely correct in C++. I can see that you prefer a different approach but my code is certainly correct C++. Please let me know when you remove the C++ tag because it seems in that case I should remove the answer. ... and please note that I read exactly what you wrote. However, it does _not_ in any way make my code "buggy".

Comment: If you have no clue about Qt, please stop posting in Qt threads. Clearly, you wildly assume Qt is just about C++11 which is by *very* far not the case. We have not even enabled the C++11 testing in the CI of Qt. I have not even looked into the standard. I cannot even tell you are correct there, but it is pointless to discuss in a Qt thread whether C++11 has it or not. Qt is more versatile, *luckily*. It is like claiming OpenGL 4 is the current standard so every hardware and driver should support it. You are miles off here IMO.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Note that I do not post to Qt "threads"! I have answered a question tagged C++ and given a C++ answer. I'm not going to refrain from answering a C++ question because it may be tagged with some technology I may not be aware off. You are free to comment in a way indicating that it isn't the recommended approach in a specific context but this is _not_ what you did. Instead, you have chosen to state "That is wrong IMHO" carrying on to advertise something not accessible to all C++ users. Should  I demand that you stop commenting on C++ questions?

Comment: "Note that I do not post to Qt "threads"!" -> This is a Qt thread marked so by the OP, indicated also by some Qt code. You have not been aware of the Qt technology, and you have now been told about the proper way IMHO. Shouldn't you be happy that you learned something new today? :) Rather, you try to be defensive, even if you are wrong. Also, this is definitely not tagged as C++11 which people use for C++11 questions. I do not understand why you defend a wrong solution that hard.

Comment: Q_GLOBAL_STATIC was introduced in Qt 5.1 . I need something for Qt 4.8 (or in C++ standard)

Comment: @Dibo: Qt 4.8 will not support C++11 properly anyway, so there is nothing in the old standard as written. Moreover, Q_GLOBAL_STATIC ** is ** available in Qt 4.8, it is just undocumented. https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/cd7aaa3820cb0b3ab777d1e8ae31379a1ef835e7:src/corelib/global/qglobal.h#L1904

Answer (score 0):

Good habit in C++ world would be to avoid global objects at all costs - the more localized is the object the better it is.

If you absolutely have to have global object, I think the best would be to initialize objects in custom order in main - to be explicit about initialization order. Fact that you are using qt is one more argument towards initializing in main - you probably would want to initialize QApplication (which requires argc and argv as input arguments) prior to any other QObject.

Comment: You cannot always initialize everything in main.